# migrate import image (image_import plugin doesn't existe)

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to import content from a csv source file, the csv file contains a field of image URL, and I'm trying to import that image using contrib modules migrate_plus, migrate_source_csv, migrate_tools.

Here is my configuration YAML file:

```
id: my_csv_import
label: Import test
migration_groups:
  - ACME import

source:
  plugin: csv
  # Full path to the file.
  path: 'news.csv'
  # Column delimiter. Comma (,) by default.
  delimiter: ','
  # Field enclosure. Double quotation marks (") by default.
  enclosure: '"'
  # The number of rows at the beginning which are not data.
  header_row_count: 1
  # The column(s) to use as a key. Each column specified will 
  # create an index in the migration table and too many columns 
  # may throw an index size error.
  keys:
    - Title

  constants:
    file_destination: 'public://images/'

process:
  title: Titre
  field_image:
    plugin: image_import
    source: Image
    destination: 'constants/file_destination'
    title: file_title
    alt: !title
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: posts

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

CSV file:

```
Titre,Image
title 1, http://my_domaine.com/images/image1.jpg
title 2, http://my_domaine.com/images/image2.jpg
```

**Question:**
While executing the command line `drush mim my_csv_import` drush return the following error message:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "image_import" plugin does not exist. in                                        [error]
/Users/brahim/void/Sites/news8/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:52
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing and enabling the contrib module [migrate_file](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file)